# PigLatin rename Tuple

Tags: apache-pig, datastax-enterprise, datastax

I am loading Data and create a Tuple:

```
data = LOAD 'file' USING PigStorage(';') AS (f1: chararray, f2: chararray);
t = FOREACH data GENERATE TOTUPLE(f1, f1) as t;
```

Later I want to rename the Tuple, sothat I have

```
t: (f3: chararray, f4: chararray)
```

Is there a possibility?

Answer (score 1):

You can provide schemas for complex data types just like you would for the basic ones:

```
grunt> data = LOAD 'file' USING PigStorage(';') AS (f1: chararray, f2: chararray);
grunt> t = FOREACH data GENERATE TOTUPLE(f1, f1) as t;
grunt> DESCRIBE t;
t: {t: (f1: chararray,f1: chararray)}
grunt> t = FOREACH t GENERATE t AS t:tuple(f3:chararray, f4:chararray);
grunt> DESCRIBE t;
t: {t: (f3: chararray,f4: chararray)}
```

If you wish, you can omit the `tuple` keyword:

```
grunt> t = FOREACH t GENERATE t AS t:(f5:chararray, f6:chararray);
grunt> DESCRIBE t;
t: {t: (f5: chararray,f6: chararray)}
```